# Grails CriteriaBuilder add Restrictions

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

I want to create my criteria object and add some restrictions dependent on some other properties.

I tried something like that ...

```
    long from, to;
    use(TimeCategory) {
        from = (1.month.ago).getTime() / 1000L
        to = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000L
    }

    def crit = Map.createCriteria()       

    // set date range
    crit.between("appear", from, to)

    // if testParam1 is present
    if (params.testParam1 && !(params.testParam1.equals("all") || params.testParam1.isEmpty())) {
        crit.eq("test1", testParam1)
    }

    // if testParam2 is present
    if (params.testParam2 && !(params.testParam2.equals("all") || params.testParam2.isEmpty())) {
        crit.eq("test2", testParam2)
    }
```

But every Time I get an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

This Exception is comming from the HibernateCriteriaBuilder class where the validateSimpleExpression test fails

```
/**
 * Creates a "between" Criterion based on the property name and specified lo and hi values
 * @param propertyName The property name
 * @param lo The low value
 * @param hi The high value
 * @return A Criterion instance
 */
public Object between(String propertyName, Object lo, Object hi) {
    if(!validateSimpleExpression()) {
        throwRuntimeException( new IllegalArgumentException("Call to [between] with propertyName ["+propertyName+"]  not allowed here."));
    }
    propertyName = calculatePropertyName(propertyName);
    return addToCriteria(Restrictions.between(propertyName, lo, hi));
}


private boolean validateSimpleExpression() {
    if(this.criteria == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any Idea how to dynamically add some Restrictions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your suggestions. It lead me to the right direction. Here's my final approach

```
long from, to;
use(TimeCategory) {
    from = (1.month.ago).getTime() / 1000L
    to = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000L
}

def records = Map.withCriteria {       

    // set date range
    between("appear", from, to)

    // if testParam1 is present
    if (params.testParam1 && !(params.testParam1.equals("all") || params.testParam1.isEmpty())) {
        eq("test1", testParam1)
    }

    // if testParam2 is present
    if (params.testParam2 && !(params.testParam2.equals("all") || params.testParam2.isEmpty())) {
        eq("test2", testParam2)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use Closure and pass it in criteria, let me show some simple example:

```
def criteria = Map.createCriteria()   


Closure closure = {builder ->
   if(params.testParam1){
       builder.eq("test1", testParam1)
   }
   if(params.testParam2){
       builder.eq("test2", testParam2)
   }
   builder.beetwen("appear", from, to)
}
```

And than :

```
 def result = criteria.list(){
    closure(criteria)        
 }
```

Comment: You can add this  as much as you want.

Comment: Do you know if the `closure()` method is unique to `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` or is that applicable throughout groovy? This is new to me...

Comment: As for me it is not unique, mb i'm wrong will try to find more info

Comment: Works for me in Grails `4.0.11`. I have many tables with similar attributes and this way I can have one builder to use in multiple places for filtering rows.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @RomanRomanovsky's answer is passing the `Closure` and then assigning the `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`'s delagate to the added closure's `delegate`:

```
def additionalRestrictions = {
   if(params.testParam1){
       eq("test1", testParam1)
   }
   ...
}

// usage
def result = criteria.list(){
    additionalRestrictions.delegate = delegate
    additionalRestrictions()       
}
```

@RomanRomanovsky's way is actually new to me and I think I prefer it.  One thing to note is that using `delegate` doesn't require anything prefixed to the methods within the closure (eq, createAlias, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is always the possibility of using Hibernate criteria queries

```
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.currentSession.createCriteria(Map.class)
        .add(Restrictions.between('appear', from, to))

    // if testParam1 is present
    if (params.testParam1 && !(params.testParam1.equals("all") || params.testParam1.isEmpty())) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("test1", testParam1))
    }
```

I ended up doing this in order to allow a function to return a Criteria, to be augmented by the caller, before being used.